# How to get push notification record from Parse in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I am developing an iOS app and backend is implemented in parse, when the app is closed and a push notification is sent, there is no way to access it inside the app, so I want to know if it's possible to access the notification sent using parse api?

Comment: If the app is opened using the notification then it will launch with the "didReceiveNotification" method. Otherwise there isn't a way.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm already aware with this. Now I wanted to know if it's possible to get a list of sent notifications from "parse.com" using their api?

Comment: Surely the notifications are just a push representation of some data in the db? So you shouldn't have to get the notifications specifically. You just need the data.

Comment: Yup the data IS present in the database. I'm sure you'll be aware of parse.com. The notifications are sent through parse.com's "push" functionality. All I wanted to know is whether parse.com provides any API functions through which I can access the notifications sent from parse. I hope I make myself clear now.

Comment: @MuhammadRaza Push notifications are not queryable. What Fogmeister was meaning was that the push you constructed is likely to be based on data from the database. You can reconstruct the Push notification based on this data. Alternatively you could create a "notification" object in Parse and save your push data there so you can query it later.

Answer (score 2):

To access to the notification, you have to go to the *AppDelegate.m* file and implement the method **didReceiveRemoteNotification**. This method receives a **NSDictionary** data with all the information of the Notification that was sent by Parse.
The content is in **json** format with, so you could retrieve it by accessing by using the key of the dictionary, and then you can create your list.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];

    NSString * keyContent = [userInfo objectForKey:@"key"];

}
```